# Как нарисовать дугу Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Хотелось бы сделать через функцию. Можно как-то без использования CGContext? Нужна именно дуга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath] ;  
        [path setLineWidth: (float)3.5];
        [path moveToPoint: p0]; // установить курсор 
        [path curveToPoint:p3 controlPoint1:p1 controlPoint2:p2];
        [path stroke];  // рисует линию